# Python agrupar valores de una columna segun la otra

Tags: python, lista

Usando Pyodbc, extraigo una lista con cada fila de la DB SQL SERVER del historico de compras de los clientes, que poseen este estilo:

("CODIGO PRODUCTO", "CLIENTE","FECHA")

```
[('02431986','JAVIER','2021-05-03 10:15:55'),
 ('01256214','JAVIER','2021-05-05 09:00:32'),
 ('02735672','JAVIER','2021-03-01 11:00:32'),
 ('05447212','PABLO','2021-05-06 14:33:15'),
 ('03985313','ALEJANDRO','2021-02-11 11:49:25'),
 ('02311513','ALEJANDRO','2021-02-11 11:49:52'),
 ('05321351','ALEJANDRO','2021-02-11 10:52:34')]
```

Mi objetivo es agrupar todos los codigos de cada cliente de las compras que halla realizado en el mes. A su vez separo en 2 tablas, los clientes que hubiesen realizad 2 0 mas compras, y los que solo realizaron una compra. Mi problema es que cuando uso el siguiente codigo que arme, se me suelen asignar codigos de otros clientes donde no corresponde.

```
 for num,inst in enumerate(table):
        try:
            if num<=(len(table)-2):
                if table[num][1]==table[num+1][1]:
                    if isinstance(inst[2],str):
                        inst[2]=datetime.strptime(inst[2],"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

                    if int(datetime.today().month)==int(datetime.strftime(inst[2], "%m")) and int(datetime.today().year)==int(datetime.strftime(inst[2], "%Y")):
                        isgroup=True
                        pat=f'{pat};{inst[0]}'



                elif table[num][1] != table[num + 1][1] and table[num][1] == table[num-1][1] and isgroup and int(datetime.today().month)==int(datetime.strftime(inst[2], "%m")) and int(datetime.today().year)==int(datetime.strftime(inst[2], "%Y")):
                    try:
                        pat = f'{pat};{inst[0]}'
                        isgroup=False
                       
                        self.cursor01.execute("insert into%s_GPP(CODIGO,CLIENTE,MES) values('%s','%s','%s')" % (self.NAME, pat[1:], inst[1],datetime.strftime(inst[2], "%m")))
                            pat=""
                    except(pyodbc.DataError):
                        pass

                else:
                    try:
                        self.cursor01.execute("insert into %s_INDIV (CODIGOS,CLIENTE,MES) values('%s','%s','%s')" % (self.NAME, inst[0], inst[1], inst[2].strftime("%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S")))
                    except(AttributeError):
                       pass
```

Pero al chequear la salida de mi codigo, se me mezclan codigos de clientes entre si, y es un caos.

Mi objetivo es que me queden tuplas de este estilo en la tabla de clientes que compro 2 o mas productos en el mes:

```
[('02431986;01256214','JAVIER','2021-05'),
 ('03985313;02311513;05321351','ALEJANDRO','2021-02')]
```

Desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: ¿Por qué no se lo dejas a la BD? `SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(codigo) AS codigo, cliente, DATE_FORMAT(fecha, "%Y-%m") AS fecha WHERE alguna_condicion FROM la_tabla GROUP BY cliente;` Una cuestión es que las fechas varían en meses lo cual las sobrescribiría. Ese problema, igual lo vas a tener en el código python.

Comment: @aeportugal Me olvide de comentar que la DB es SQL SERVER, fijandome en internet la funcion GROUP_CONCAT() es de mySQL. No me molesta que sobreescriba las fechas, mientras todas pertenescan al mismo mes de compras de cada cliente me es indistinto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puedes utilizar `filter` sobre la lista para filtrar los resultados. Lo primero que hice fue filtrar el nombre de los usuarios, utilice `set` para obtener los valores unicos o los nombres de usuario diferentes de la lista.

```
# OBTENER USUARIOS DIFERENTES
usuarios_diferentes = list(set([usuario for compra, usuario, fecha in compras]))
resultado = []

# PROCESAR INFORMACION DE CADA USUARIO
for usuario in usuarios_diferentes:
    # FILTRAR COMPRAS DE USUARIO
    compras_usuario = list(filter(lambda tup: tup[1] == usuario, compras))
    # FILTRAR FECHAS DE COMPRAS
    fechas = list(set([f[:7] for c, u, f in compras_usuario]))

    for fecha in fechas:
        # FILTRAR COMPRAS DE USUARIO EN ESA FECHA
        compras_fecha = list(filter(lambda tup: tup[2][:7] == fecha, compras_usuario))

        if len(compras_fecha) > 1: # TIENE MAS DE UNA COMPRA EN ESA FECHA(MES)
            str_compras = ';'.join([c for c, u, f in compras_fecha])
            resultado.append((str_compras, usuario, fecha,))

print(resultado) # [('03985313;02311513;05321351', 'ALEJANDRO', '2021-02'), ('02431986;01256214', 'JAVIER', '2021-05')]
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciono a la perfeccion!! Estoy super crudo con el manejo de listas, pero ver a los profesionales es una buena forma de seguir aprendiendo. muy amable por responder

Comment: Gracias. Utilizo conceptos muy interesantes. El primero son las `list comprehension`, que lo utilice por ejemplo en este for `[usuario for compra, usuario, fecha in compras]`. El otro son las expresiones `lambda`, que son funciones anónimas. `filter` que son filtros que aplican a `iterables` mediante funciones, aqui es donde entran las `lambda`.

Comment: Podrias reemplazar los filters por lists comprehension y funcionaría igual y se vería más entendible.

Comment: Puede hacerse de muchas formas. En lo personal es mas clara la palabra `filter`. En este ejemplo es cuestion de gustos. En la vida real hay que intentar que sea claro y eficiente. Me parece que la respuesta de @Bryro es menos entendible pero mas eficiente.

Answer (score 0):

no es la solucion mas elegante pero espero te funcione:

```
  inputdata = [('02431986','JAVIER','2021-05-03 10:15:55'),
 ('01256214','JAVIER','2021-05-05 09:00:32'),
 ('02735672','JAVIER','2021-03-01 11:00:32'),
 ('05447212','PABLO','2021-05-06 14:33:15'),
 ('03985313','ALEJANDRO','2021-02-11 11:49:25'),
 ('02311513','ALEJANDRO','2021-02-11 11:49:52'),
 ('05321351','ALEJANDRO','2021-02-11 10:52:34')]

tmp = {}
res = []
# recorremos la tupla
for num,name,date in inputdata:
    # cortamos la fecha
    dr = date[0:7]
    # validmos que no exista la llave
    if not tmp.get(name+dr):
        # agregamos la llave + la fecha cortada y su data
        tmp[name+dr] = [num,name,dr]
    else:
        # concatenamos el string
        tmp[name+dr][0] +=  ";"+ num

# validamos mas de 2 resultados
for i in tmp:
    # validamos que tengas por lo menos 1 punto y coma
    if tmp[i][0].count(";") >0:
        # agregamso al resultado
        # convertimos a tuple
        res.append(tuple(tmp[i]))

# resultado esperado
wim = [('02431986;01256214','JAVIER','2021-05'),
 ('03985313;02311513;05321351','ALEJANDRO','2021-02')]

# validamos que coincidan
assert wim == res
```

Comment: La lista de resultado debe ser una lista de tuplas. Igual funciona bien

Comment: listo solventado perdon!

Comment: Explendido!!! Aunque utilize la otra respuesta, la tuya me funciono tambien de la misma manera. Muchas gracias por tu tiempo!